# How do i handle closing WebView that opened in Activity Android?

Tags: android, webview

Hello i have a weird thing here, i have a list of items and i want when i click on any item, it will open an WebView which looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"> 

<WebView android:id="@+id/BrowserView"  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"                
         android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

here is the code i invoke the WebView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
            setContentView(R.layout.external_view);

            // load url or html
            RssItem listItem = (RssItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.BrowserView);

            // set browser settings
            webView.setWebViewClient(new ExternalWebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
            webView.setInitialScale(1);

            try {
                webView.loadUrl(listItem.getExternalUrl());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d("WEBVIEW", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the "ExternalWebViewClient" class

```
public class ExternalWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.clearHistory();
}
```

}

Now the question:

How do i close it and stay in the same activity after i press the "back" button,
here is my back button handling code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (webView.canGoBack() == true) {
                webView.goBack();
            } else {
                //what should i do here?????????????????                    
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should not need to handle Back button yourself. If you are in the WebView and press Back - you should be taken to your last activity by default.

Comment: I am not using it as an activity, i open it in the listview activity.

Comment: OK, sorry, I looked too fast.

Comment: have solved it with your way, couldn't find any suggestion for my problem, any way i will set your answer!
Thaks